# MATLAB object oriented GUI

Tags: oop, matlab, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global (shared) variables in Matlab GUI code behind. Is there better way to do it then using handles structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595040/global-shared-variables-in-matlab-gui-code-behind-is-there-better-way-to-do-i)

I couldn't find any information about it, this is what I want to archive.

I want to create GUI classes similar to standard Windows OOP. For example I want to create a class representing a window which would contain definitions of children objects such as buttons, lists and so on.

I would create that object in the main .m file and go from there. Is something like that possible in MATLAB?
If not, which approach should I have?

Can you give me a simple code from where I would start, e.g. a class definition for a simple window and a main .m file declaring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

------ FigGUI.m --------

```
classdef FigGUI < handle
    properties
        fig
    end
    methods
        function obj = FigGUI(varargin)
            obj.fig = figure(varargin{:});
        end
        function clear_figure(obj)
            clf(obj.fig);
        end
        % ... more methods
    end
end
```

Construction example:

```
f = FigGUI('Position', [560   528   560   420], 'Name', 'GUI');
f.clear_figure();
```

... and so on